# Try is not executed while catch is not catching

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I am creating delete functionality in asp.net mvc, I get the Null reference "null entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type" when I put in Try-Catch Block.
when I remove Try-Catch Block, then I get "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_tbl_Url_tbl_Category". "

```
public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
{
    try
    {
        objBs.Delete(Id);

        return Redirect("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        "Sorry Failed to delete!"
        ViewBag.DeleteData = e;
        return Redirect("Index");
    }
}
```

The only question in mind is that why I am getting different error just due to Try-Catch Block.
Secondly, why Catch Block is not catching my error when try can't be successful executed.

Comment: how your Index action looks like?

Comment: This is not compilable.  Show us what you're *actually* doing.

Comment: Can MVC 4 be used with .net core?  The tags don't look right to me.

Comment: If you always want to `return Redirect("Index");` (whether or not an exception occurs), you can reduce duplicated code by putting that in a `finally` block.

Comment: Probably you have two exceptions happening, one in the try and one in the catch. So without the try/catch you hit the first one, and with the try catch, the first one is handled by the catch so you see the second one.

Comment: @RufusL Agree with Rufus L comment, That is the case where it can happen like this.

Answer (score 0):

please check your ID, which is coming for the delete, is exits in database table or not, and if exits then please make sure the reference of that ID, Child Should Remove first then Parent. Then only your Delete Functionality will work.